# headers['transformRequest'] = angular.identity

Tags: angular

Please let me know what is the equivalent of headers['transformRequest'] = angular.identity to the latest version. In Angular 1.x we are using and uploading a content in documentum content managment system but i am not sure the equivalent in the latest version.

Please let me know if any suggestions/comments.

thanks
vinod.

Comment: this headers is http headers or something else?

Comment: those of var type

Comment: headers[dctmConstants.HEADERS.CONTENT_TYPE] = undefined
            headers['transformRequest'] = angular.identity